# CSS transition issue with horizontal scroll list items

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, mousehover

I have horizontal list with list items. If you hover the mouse on it, it expands horizontally to make space to show more infos (not implemented)

**However I can't figure out why the items are moving down when i hover over it.**

https://embed.plnkr.co/51WuwdhmH7yS3pSnkqFY/

(The overlapping thing is just is just plunker i guess)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a very simple fix: in your CSS add `vertical-align: top;` to `.thread-item`. This will keep the elements on top at all time ;)